# JBoss Forge IDEA Plugin - No Spring Boot Option?

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, jboss-forge

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 with the JBoss Forge IDEA Plugin.

I saw a video of using it, http://vimeo.com/180053437 at 3:17 you can see the menu with Spring Boot included. When they select "Project:New", it shows the "Project Type" drop down menu, including a "Spring Boot" option. I don't see that option in my menu. Here is a video of the behavior on my machine - [youtu.be/TJ3aWf0wlX8](http://youtu.be/TJ3aWf0wlX8)

I do have the Spring Boot plugin v1.0 installed as well, and it works from the IntelliJ new project menu. Any ideas on getting this option?

Comment: Did you install IntelliJ Community Edition or Ultimatum ?

Comment: @Anton Dozortsev - Ultimate 2016.2

Comment: Post a link to video that you have mentioned on your question.

Answer (score 2):

I 've had the some problem but with eclipse.
I've installed the fabric8 forge plugin https://fabric8.io/guide/forge.html

addon-install --coordinate io.fabric8.forge:camel,2.3.80

addon-install --coordinate io.fabric8.forge:camel-commands,2.3.80

addon-install --coordinate io.fabric8.forge:devops,2.3.80

addon-install --coordinate io.fabric8.forge:kubernetes,2.3.80

and now works

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this now and it looks like it's been renamed to "microservice"

Comment: Oops, nope. You need to add the addons above, but up to 2.3.86